# Scala optimizing optional string parsing

Tags: scala, option-type, stringtemplate

We need to create an request query-string, from a case class. The case class contains optional attributes:

```
case class Example(..., str: Option[String], ..)
```

We want to create a query-parameter if the option exists, and no query parameter otherwise. Like:

```
match example.str {
  case Some(s) => s"&param_str=$s"
  case _ => ""
}
```

as this appearing at numerous places I want it to make a bit more generic:

```
def option2String(optionString: Option[String], template: String) = {
optionString match {
  case Some(str) => template.replaceAll("\\$str", str)
  case _ =>  ""
}
```

But I think it can be done more elegant or scala idiomatic, may be with `call-by-name arguments?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use fold

```
example.str.fold("")("&param_str=" + _)
```

If you have multiple parameters you can try this:

```
List(
  str1.map("&param1_str=" + _),
  str2.map("&param2_str=" + _),
  str3.map("&param3_str=" + _)
).flatten.mkString(" ")
```

Comment: Thanks! too bad `example.str.fold("")(s"&param_str=$_")` is not allowed.

Comment: Is not allowed? You could also use a map / getOrElse combination.

Comment: `example.str.fold("")(s => s"&param_str=$s")` removes the string concat

Comment: @drjerry I chose that particular version because I thought it looked cleanest, and it is likely to be the most efficient, but other variants are certainly possible.